# Center divs in body horizontally and vertically with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center some `div`s vertically and horizontally using flexbox but it's not working as expected.
here is an image illustrating what am having and what I expect.

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<html lang="en">

<body>

<style type="text/css">

    body{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
</style>

    <div>111111</div>
    <div>222222</div>
    <div>333333</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

Of course, I know it'd be better puting the `div`s in a container and that's what I tried first but in that case, I end up with something like this:

[image]

So as you can see, the `div`s are get centred in the container as expected but the container itself is not.

Comment: why not use `display:table` instead?

Comment: @NoobEditor I don't know how display table work yet... Will check it though.

Comment: i find it much simpler that `flex`, and `vertical-align` is extremely usable in this case....search for `css tables`!!

Comment: Yeah, on my to do notes. so much to learn :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need align-content: center to run

```
align-content : center
```

See this:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-content/

I recommend to you to nest objects in a div. Change the body behaviour is dangerous.

Answer (score 10):

Your code is fine, you should only add a `min-height: 100vh` to the `body` so the div can be centered in the viewport height (the body doesn't always cover the viewport height, it just takes minimal space to contain its children)

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGQpKO

Answer (score 6):

Add this

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/1Luo758m/